# Print to pdf in Excel on Mac (Landscape and file destination)

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I use Office 365 on MacOs 12.4 (Monterrey)

I want to print my spreadsheet as Landscape to a .pdf file. It prints as Portrait.

As far as I can see it is difficult to choose the file path on MacOs due to sandboxing. So far it will only output to the Excel folder.

```vb
Sheets(1).Select
Range("A1:CH55").Select
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$CH$55"
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
End With
    
Range("A1:CH55").Select
Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:="name.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
  IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

My two questions are:

1. How do I decide the output folder?
2. How do I print in Landscape?

Answer (score 0):

After a long search I found a workaround and a solution.

1. Ron de Bruin's website [www.macexcel.com](http://www.macexcel.com) has code that sort of fixes that. I just hadn't copied the function part of the code, so that is why it didn't work.
2. Ron de Bruin mentions that it is a bug. I couldn't get his bug fix to work, so I had to rethink how I wanted the document printed, so I could print it as portrait.